# Setting Default font to Kendo UI Editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, editor

I have a requirement to set the default font value to Impact when the user starts typing the text without selecting the font in the Kendo Editor. But, when the user selects a font and then starts typing in the text the Editor should honor the font selection. I was able to set the Inherited font to Impact by adding a new style sheet to the body element while initializing the editor. Now, the font of the text is Impact but, the font value which is shown in the Font Select combo box is still inherit font. Now, my question is .. Is there any way to change the font to Impact when there is no content in the editable area and no there is not font selected. Also, I don't want to bind this font change to either Keydown or Keyup events of the editor as it would effect the performance of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution ... Setting the default font in keydown event of the editor like this,

> keydown: function (e) { if (this.getRange().startOffset == 0
>   &&this.getRange).endOffset == 0 &&
>   this.encodedValue().localeCompare('')== 0) { this.exec("fontName", {
>   value: 'Impact' }); } }

Since for every keypress there will be a loop to test the condition thereby impacting the performance of the editor. It's a patchy solution but, works :)

Comment: I got this solution: `keydown: function (e) {
                            if ((this.getRange().startOffset === 0) && this.getRange().endOffset === 0 && this.encodedValue().localeCompare('') === 1 )
                            
                            { this.exec("fontName", { value: 'PoloHint' }); } },`

Answer (score -1):

You can set font inherit name through Editor `message` configuration

**Sample**

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
    messages: {
        fontNameInherit: "Impact"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response ... If I am not wrong (correct me if so) the soln u hve suggested will rename "inherited font" option value to Impact. But, let us say the user copy pastes the text into the editor and the pasted font is not predefined, then the font select box shows Impact as the selected font, which confuses the user So, I am looking for setting the font name programmatically

Comment: I agree, you need that also.